# How to make angular change value on submit?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Can someone please instruct me what to do, so that when I press on "submit" button the myName variable gets updated? Thanks!

app.js:

```
app.controller('SomeController', ['$scope', 'emails', function($scope, emails) {
  emails.success(function(data) {

    $scope.emails = data;
  });

    $scope.myName = "John"; 

}]);
```

view.html

```
<div ng-controller="SomeController">
    <form name="messageForm" ng-submit="update(myName)">
      <input type="text" ng-model="myName"/>
        <h1>{{myName}}</h1>
      <input type="submit" value="Send Message"/>
    </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

This will update as long as you type:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myName"/>
<h1>{{myName}}</h1>
```

This will only update when you hit submit:

```
<form name="messageForm" ng-submit="update(myName)">
  <input type="text" ng-model="myName"/>
    <h1>{{myUpdatedName}}</h1>
  <input type="submit" value="Send Message"/>
</form>
```

on your controller you should have:

```
$scope.update = function(name) {
  $scope.myUpdatedName = name;
};
```

Just keep in mind that your form should be wrapped in any component that is declaring your `SomeController`... for example a

```
<div ng-controller="SomeController">
  <!-- your form goes here -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing the update function in your controller:

```
app.controller('SomeController', ['$scope', 'emails', function($scope, emails) {
  emails.success(function(data) {

    $scope.emails = data;
  });

  $scope.myName = "John"; 
  $scope.update = function(name) {
    $scope.myName = name;
  };

}]);
```

Comment: Yes clearly I missed it. This is a step in the right direction but it doesnt seem to work. It doesnt update the variable for me when I click on submit.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? I suspect it could be caused by the emails.success... part, that syntax is very weird.